# How to click on an element within an iframe with Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have the following  element inside an iframe. This tag displays a ">" icon and will flip to the next graph on the URL when the user clicks on it. You can see it in the following URL where it says

**< 1 of 16 >**

https://msdh.ms.gov/msdhsite/_static/14,21995,420,873.html

```
<a>
<i class="glyphicon glyph-small pbi-glyph-chevronrightmedium middleIcon active pbi-focus-outline" focus-element="" tabindex="0" title="Next Page">
</i>
</a>
```

Using Selenium how can I send a click action to this element to flip to the next graph?

```
url='https://msdh.ms.gov/msdhsite/_static/14,21995,420,873.html'
p='my/path/to/chromedriver'
driver=webdriver.Chrome(p)
driver.get(url)
myframe=driver.find_element_by_class_name("flexibleFrame")
driver.switch_to.frame(myframe)
i = driver.find_element_by_class_name("glyphicon")
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try `i.click()`? I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. My class selector was selecting the left Chevron so click didn't do anything as there is nothing to flip to. I fixed the selector and now its working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

The **`>`** icon is within a `<iframe>` so to interact with the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *visibility_of_element_located()*.
- `scrollIntoView()` the *WebElement*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://msdh.ms.gov/msdhsite/_static/14,21995,420,873.html')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.flexibleFrame")))
  elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i.glyphicon.glyph-small.pbi-glyph-chevronrightmedium.middleIcon.active.pbi-focus-outline[title='Next Page']")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem)
  elem.click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://msdh.ms.gov/msdhsite/_static/14,21995,420,873.html')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='flexibleFrame']")))
  elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='glyphicon glyph-small pbi-glyph-chevronrightmedium middleIcon active pbi-focus-outline' and @title='Next Page']")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem)
  elem.click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: msdhsite]

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)